# Очищение строки и "вытаскивание" текста

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, текст

Есть такая строка:

```
[00:21:53] Администратор Hello_World[472] для Hello_WorldTwo[187]: Привет. Хорошо.
```

Как отсюда можно вытащить "Привет. Хорошо."?

И да, текст может быть разный.

Вместо "Привет. Хорошо." может быть что угодно, хоть "5 минут, полёт нормальный".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Регуляркой описываем что нужная информация (в круглых скобках) начинается после строки, начинающейся с `[`, после идет любой набор данных и заканчивается это `]:`

```
import re

text = '[00:21:53] Администратор Hello_World[472] для Hello_WorldTwo[187]: Привет. Хорошо.'

match = re.search(r'\[.+\]:(.+)', text)
print(match[1])  # ' Привет. Хорошо.'
```

Comment: Воу, спасибо Вам! А то 30 минут думал, как это сделать...

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) ;)

Answer (score 1):

При такой простой структуре сообщения и обычная питоновская функция `split` могла бы подойти. Просто делим строку по подстроке `']: '`:

```
text = '[00:21:53] Администратор Hello_World[472] для Hello_WorldTwo[187]: Привет. Хорошо.'
print(text.split(']: ')[1])
```

Вывод:

```
Привет. Хорошо.
```